# Negative zero in one's complement

Tags: computer-science

Why there is a negative 0 in one's complement?

What does it mean?

Why does the positive zero has a different value in one's complement?

[image]

The calculator that I used is found here: http://www.convertforfree.com/ones-complement-calculator/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement#Negative_zero

Comment: Because that's what you get if you apply the one's complement operation to +0 ...

Comment: That's why two's complement exists and can represent one additional number compared to one's complement. in two's complement you only get positive zero.